# Timestamps look different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, timestamp

In Rails, I find that timestamps in the console look different to the actual html view even when you have the same code. Unless I'm doing something really stupid:

```
>> article = News.first
=> #<News id: 1, title: "Testing", body: "yadda yadda", role_id: 1, created_at: "2009-04-12 05:33:07", updated_at: "2009-04-12 05:33:07">
>> article.created_at
=> Sun, 12 Apr 2009 05:33:07 UTC +00:00
>> article.created_at.to_date
=> Sun, 12 Apr 2009
```

And in the view:

```
<% for article in @news %>
    <% @current_date = article.created_at.to_date %>
    <% if @current_date != @date %>
        <%= @current_date %>
        <% @date = @current_date %>
    <% end %>
```

The output will be:

```
2009-04-14
```

Why are the formats different?

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/57923#47559

Comment: @Michael: Rails now supports YAML locales, so that method is outdated.

Comment: Hmmmm... so how do I get my dates to look like "Sun, 12 Apr 2009"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config/initializers/time_formats.rb, write:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:article] = "%a, %d %B %Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%=` calls `to_s` on the `Date` object, which results in `2009-04-14` no matter where it's called:

```
>> Date.today
=> Tue, 14 Apr 2009
>> Date.today.to_s
=> "2009-04-14"
```

I really don't know what gets called when you don't use `to_s`.

**UPDATE:** Now I know. If you don't use `to_s` or an equivalent, `irb` calls `inspect` on the date object:

```
>> Date.today.inspect
=> "Tue, 14 Apr 2009"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

You can replace `@current_date` with `@current_date.to_s` (or `@current_date.to_s(:format)`) in your view. Format can be short, long, db, long_ordinal, rfc822 or number.

You can also define a default date format in your application locale.

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Conversions.html#M001236